# Dictionary realization for multiple tables in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have so strange question connected with realization of dictionary (handbook, etc.) with description of, for example, work types. Let me explain.

Let me have 2 classes:

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WorkType> WorkTypes { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<WorkType> WorkTypes { get; set; }
}
```

where

```
public class WorkType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and my context is:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PurchaseOrder> { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I make a migration, I get 2 additional columns in my `WorkType` table: `OrderId` and `PurchaseOrderId`.
So, I don't want to have them in this table, of course. Is it possible to make this N:M relation without FK?
Possible I can have WorkType collections in many classes.

Thank you.

P.S. I use EF Core 6.0.6

Comment: What columns are in the database?  Migration simply updated the mapping between the database tables and the c# classes.

Comment: @jdweng As I've mentioned, I got 2 additional columns in `WorkType` table: `OrderId` and `PurchaseOrderId`. EF Core created these columns automatically, but if I'm not mistaken, in this case I'll get N:1 relation.

Comment: EF Core cannot automatically create columns.  You are using DbContext so you have a database and Core is just getting the columns from the database.

Comment: @jdweng you are not correct.  Add-Migration -Name "MyDbMigration" -Context "MyDbContext" and Update-Database -Context "MyDbContext" do exactly what I have written.

Comment: Where are the new columns coming from if not from the database? Did you even check the tables in the database?

Comment: @jdweng As I've already mentioned, I do not use existing schema, but just create tables via migration. Check this: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx

Comment: This is normal behavior. These columns are foreign keys. Without them, it is impossible to relations your tables/models. See docs: [Shadow and Indexer Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Maybe you could recommend me another possible solution for this case? ((( I don't want to have so many FKs in this table...

Comment: If you delete foreign keys, how do you associate WorkType with a specific Order or PurchaseOrder?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Now I understand my mistake, but cannot find feasible solution for my case, unfortunatelly. (((